# How do I mock chained function in jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I use jest to test my node.js code. I need to connect to mongodb using mongoose. But I don't know how to mock the chained function.

the function I need to mock(Vessels is a module):

```js
return await Vessels.find({}).exec();
```

the way I tried to mock, but it fails:

```js
 Vessels.find.exec = jest.fn(() => [mockVesselResponse]);
```

I want to mock chained function `Vessels.find({}).exec()`, anyone here can helps me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Naïve way is to mock method `find` that would return object with method `exec`(check Jest docs on [ways to mock modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) for details):

```
import Vessels from '/path/to/vessels';

jest.mock('/path/to/vessels'); 
Vessels.prototype.find.mockReturnThis();
Vessels.prototype.exclude.mockReturnThis();
Vessels.prototype.anyOtherChainingCallMethod.mockReturnThis();

it('your test', () => {
   Vessels.prototype.exec.mockResolvedValueOnce([youdata]);
   // your code here
});
```

but it seems to me quite long way with a lot of manual work on mocking every single internal method.

Instead I propose you mocking one level deeper. Say with mocking `mongoose` models with [`mockingoose`](https://github.com/alonronin/mockingoose).

Have never worked with `mongoose` so cannot provide sample for this approach.

Comment: I have tried like this `jest.mock("../mongo/models");  Vessels.find.mockReturnThis();` , In test I use `Vessels.exec.mockResolvedValueOnce([mockVesselResponse]);`. But it still doesn't work, the error is : **TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockResolvedValueOnce' of undefined**.  I tried to understand Jest docs about this, but it is tricky and not very relevant to my problem.

Comment: I just tried mockingoose, luckily it works:) `mockingoose(Vessels).toReturn([mockVesselResponse, mockVesselResponse2], 'find');`

Comment: oh, it should be `Vessels.prototype.find.mockReturnThis`

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the function in the return of the value.

```
jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ exec: () => vesselMockObject })
```